# Negative R2 values

Tags: r, formula, xgboost

While generating accuracy metrics for a model I'm returning negative R2 values. The model is taking Principal compnents and train/test (80/20) in an XGboost model. I cant tell if I'm using an incorrect formula or the problem lies in the model. The dataset produces positive R2 values while using a basic polynomial regression model.

Formulas for MAE, MSE, R2 and adjusted R2. I expected R2 values around 0.6, but have manged to generate negative values.

```
r_squared_list_pc <- lapply(1:length(target_variables), function(i) {
  1 - sum((predictions_list_pc[[i]] - y_test_pc[, i])^2) /
    sum((y_test_pc[, i] - mean(y_test_pc[, i]))^2)
})

adjusted_r_squared_list_pc <- lapply(1:length(target_variables), function(i) {
  n <- length(y_test_pc[, i])
  p <- length(xgb_models_pc[[i]]$model$feature_names)
  1 - ((r_squared_list_pc[[i]]) * (n - 1)) / (n - p - 1)
})
```

[[i]] is used to iterate through mutliple targets.

Comment: Your calculation of adjusted R² is wrong. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2

Answer (score 0):

The below example works for unweighted linear regression models and not sure if the same principles apply for XGBoost models.

#### Example

```
r_squared <- function(y, fitted, intercept = TRUE){
  resid <- fitted - y
  rss <- sum(resid^2)
  if (intercept){
    mss <- sum((fitted - mean(y))^2)
  } else {
    mss <- sum(fitted^2)
  }
  tss <- rss + mss
  1 - (rss / tss)
}

mod <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)

r_squared(iris$Sepal.Width, fitted(mod))
[1] 0.01382265
```

Without seeing your data, you could try something like this.

```
r_squared_list_pc <- lapply(1:length(target_variables), function(i) {
  r_squared(y_test_pc[, i], predictions_list_pc[[i]])
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for R2 seems correct to me, so predictions might be different from real targets.

Could you explore the residuals for any of the target variables where you find R2<0? Something like this:

```
i=1
# Residuals of your model:
summary(predictions_list_pc[[i]] - y_test_pc[, i])
# Residuals using mean as predictor:
summary(y_test_pc[, i] - mean(y_test_pc[, i]))
```

This should give you an idea of how the residuals are distributed for any target variable i. A good prediction would have an average of around zero and low variation. Comparing residuals distribution can help you understand if this is because of your model's predictions.

Comment: Yes. It's not my formula. My model is causing the problem. I appreciate your time.